# How could i read all my unread / new mail from different accounts in one group or topic?

Tags: gnus

i want to read all my unread /new messages from different IMAP accounts in one Gnus group. As far as i read in the manual, it could be possible with topics or virtual groups.

But i do not understand how i could configure it.

Any clues?

I'm on Linux Mint 19.1 with Emacs 26.1.

Answer (score 0):

i just managed it to bring it together.
I configure it with nnvirtual server. As far as i understood the regexp, the server was filled with the groups and voila: my mails are listed together.
Command G c.
and at the bottom of the page:
(nnvirtual "^nnimap\+GMail\:INBOX$\|^nnimap\+Jens_Privat\:INBOX$\|^nnimap\+Jens_Reimer\:INBOX$\|^nnimap\+Karl\:INBOX$")
Thats all.
It works
Poul